# Complete expression for $3\cos^{-1}x$

Tags: trigonometry, inverse-function

> Complete expression for $3\cos^{-1}x$

**My Attempt**

Let $a=\cos^{-1}x\implies x=\cos a$
$$
\cos3a=4\cos^3a-3\cos a=4x^3-3x=\sin\bigg[\sin^{-1}\Big(4x^3-3x\Big)\bigg]\\
3a=3\cos^{-1}x=2n\pi\pm\cos^{-1}\Big(4x^3-3x\Big)\\
\boxed{\cos^{-1}\Big(4x^3-3x\Big)=2n\pi\pm\big(3\cos^{-1}x\big)}
$$
$$
a=\cos^{-1}x\in [0,\pi]\implies3a\in[0,3\pi]
$$
**Case 1:** $3a\in [0,\pi]$
$$
\color{darkblue}{3\cos^{-1}x=\cos^{-1}\Big(4x^3-3x\Big)}\\
3\cos^{-1}x\in [0,\pi]\implies\cos^{-1}x\in [0,\pi/3]\implies x\in [1/2,1]
$$

**Case 2:** $3a\in (\pi,2\pi]$
$$
\color{darkblue}{3\cos^{-1}x=2\pi-\cos^{-1}\Big(4x^3-3x\Big)}\\
3\cos^{-1}x\in (\pi,2\pi]\implies\cos^{-1}x\in (\pi/3,2\pi/3]\implies x\in [-1/2,1/2)
$$
**Case 3:** $3a\in (2\pi,3\pi]$
$$
\color{darkblue}{3\cos^{-1}x=-2\pi+\cos^{-1}\Big(4x^3-3x\Big)}\\
3\cos^{-1}x\in (2\pi,3\pi]\implies\cos^{-1}x\in (2\pi/3,\pi]\implies x\in [-1,-1/2)
$$
How do I confirm that my attempt provides a complete expression for $3\cos^{-1}x$.

Comment: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1243735/differentiating-the-function-arcsin3x-4x3/1243781#1243781

Comment: @labbhattacharjee the post u mentioned talks abt similar expression for $3\sin^{-1}x$. Could u please comment on the case with $3\cos^{-1}x$ ?